# Translational Correlation function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions

I have to compute the translational correlation function of a 2 dimensional set of particles. The function is given in literature like following:

$$
G_k(r) = \sum_{l = 1}^6\frac{1}{N}\sum_{<j,k>}^{N_r} e^{-i q_l ( r_k-r_j)}
$$

Where q are the 6 reciprocal lattice vectors derived from the first order Bragg peaks in the structure factor of the set and r are the real space positions of the particles. So far I have been able to calculate the reciprocal lattice vectors but I struggle in understanding what I have to do to calculate the correlation function. Another definition I found seems to be equal but still as confusing:

$$
G_k(r) = \sum_{l = 1}^6\frac{1}{2 \pi r \Delta r }\sum_{j,k}^{N_r} \zeta(r - |r_k-r_j|)e^{-i q_l ( r_k-r_j)}
$$

with $\zeta$ being 1 for r $\approx$ r+ $\Delta$ r

How can I calculate this function numerically? Can somebody help me out with a short pseudo-code?

Comment: Could you provide the source where the function is given in the first form in the literature?

Comment: Melting of a skyrmion lattice to a skyrmion liquid
via a hexatic phase

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41565-020-0716-3

Answer (score 1):

I will forget about the first sum over inner brag  because it is not necessary.

When you write down this:
$$G_k(r) = \dfrac{1}{N}\left\langle\sum_{<j,k>}^{N_r} e^{-i q ( r_k-r_j)}\right\rangle$$

You assume that the value at $r$ is averaged over a lot of $k$ and $j$ such that $r_j - r_k = r$ exactly. However, it is of course not the case in your simulation since you have a finite number of particles, you will have a finite number of distances. What you do to fix this issue is binning.

You'll say that $G(r)$ is approximately equal to the sum of every terms (j, k): $e^{-i q ( r_k-r_j)}$ such that $r<|r_k - r_j|< r+dr $ with $dr$ small enough. This is more or less your last equation.

In an algorithmic way, what do you do?

- You compute every distances: $|r_{jk}|$ and every exponential associated $g_{jk} = e^{qr_{jk}}$
- You create an array $G$ which contains M = (int)(L/2)/dr elements (with L/2: half the size of your system, or whatever is the largest distance making sense in your system). This will be the approximation of the real function G(r). Except that it is binned by $dr$.
- You map the distances $r_{ij}$ to indices by: index$_{ij}$ = $r_{ij}/dr$ and then you fill the array $G$ with the exponential corresponding to the right indices. For example in $G[4]$ you will have the average of exponentials $\sum_{ij}e^{qr_{ij}}$ such that $r_{ij}\in [4dr; 5dr]$.

Here is a minimal implementation with gx and gy one of my bragg peak (note the use of a cos() instead of an exponential because of $r_{ij}=-r_{ji}$ and hence, the $j$ sum going to $i$ and not $N$. I also included periodic boundary conditions) :

[image]